# Why I am able to change member of an object which is passed as constant reference?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Student {
private:
    int age;
public:
    char *name;
    Student(int age,char*name) {
        this->age=age;
        this->name=new char[strlen(name)+1];
        strcpy(this->name,name);
    }
    Student(Student const &s1) {
        this->age=s1.age;
        this->name=new char[strlen(s1.name)+1];
        strcpy(this->name,s1.name);
        s1.name[0]='x';
    }
    void display() {
        cout<<age<<" "<<name<<endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    char name[]="abcd";
    Student s1(10,name);
    s1.display();
    Student s2(s1);
    s2.name[0]='x';
    s1.display();
    s2.display();
}
```

I have passed s1 as a constant reference but I am able to change s1.name[0] and the program compiles successfully. Why I am able to change s1.name[0]?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aqna.png)

Comment: Note that the member is the pointer here, and you didn't modify the pointer. You should use `std::string` instead of `char *` if you want constness to apply to the content of the string.

Comment: So if I use char * instead of string, I will not be able to make each and every character const?

Comment: That's right, only the pointer will be const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not modify `s1`. You modified some unrelated memory block (allocated by `new`)  , to which `s1` holds a pointer. In C++ there is no special relationship between a raw pointer and any memory block it might happen to be pointing to.

If you use `std::string` instead of raw pointers and manual memory management then this problem will not arise.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can it be resolved without the use of string class?

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said this is because `s1` is const, so you cannot modify the pointer `s1.name`. However, the memory `s1.name` is pointing at is not const.

If you **really** cannot use `std::string`, you might want to have a look at [std::experimental::propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const). This is a wrapper for any pointer type, in your case a raw pointer, that will, as the name suggests, propagate its constness to the memory it points at.

But as I can hardly imagine any circumstances where you are not able/allowed to use an `std` class (`string`), but an `std::experimental` class would be ok, this is likely not an option for you. However, you might get inspired by the idea and write your own string class.

Note in case you are not aware: you are missing a corresponding `delete` for your `new`. `std::string` would do that for you. So, if you write your own string class, make sure that one also does that.